# How to delete a document through DocumentReference using where? Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to delete a document in Firestore, you can delete the data based on uid, but i does not wan to use uid. I wan it to compare the a String value with the firestore database data, then only it delete the entire document. How can i do that?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and show us the exact data you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not support so-called delete queries (or update queries), where you send a condition and an operation to the database.

Instead you will have to:

1. [Run a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) that matches the document that you want to delete.
2. [Loop through the `QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) that you get back from that.
3. [Delete each document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) in turn.